# Page break row number

Tags: c#, epplus, page-break

How do I find the position of page breaks using EPPlus as it's simply

```
int firstPagebreakRowNo = worksheet.HPageBreaks[1].Location.Row;
```

in Interop methodology (I abandoned this as it was so slow)?

Answer (score 0):

No easy way I have seen other then looping through the rows and columns.  You can use the `MaxRows` and `MaxColumns` as bounds at least:

```
worksheet.Row(2).PageBreak = true;
worksheet.Row(3).PageBreak = true;

Console.Write("Row Breaks: ");
for (var i = 1; i <= ExcelPackage.MaxRows; i++)
    if (worksheet.Row(i).PageBreak)
        Console.Write($"{i} ");  // Writes: "Row Breaks: 2 3 "

worksheet.Column(4).PageBreak = true;
worksheet.Column(15).PageBreak = true;

Console.Write("Col Breaks: ");
for (var i = 1; i <= ExcelPackage.MaxColumns; i++)
    if (worksheet.Column(i).PageBreak)
        Console.Write($"{i} ");  // Writes: "Col Breaks: 4 15"
```

Comment: This will only give manual page breaks. What about auto page breaks ?

Comment: @JaydeepKarena I would recommend posting a separate question what it is your looking to do.

Comment: I found my answer. Excel doesn't allow removing auto page breaks.