# How to extract page breaks in EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

When using Excel interop service to get page breaks

```
Activesheet.HPageBreaks
```

What is the equivalent in EPPlus to extract page breaks?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997109/1324284  Note that epplus does not actually render the excel files so it probably will not be able to tell you auto page breaks since that will be decided when Excel proper opens it.

Answer (score -1):

`HPageBreaks` is the sheet's property containing all of the page breaks. `Activesheet.HPageBreaks` should work just fine and return the horizontal page breaks.

Comment: How do you extract page breaks in EPPlus not in excel introp ?